# Consolidated analysis

Tags: views, 6, userpoints

Using [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module for Drupal 6, how do I create a table that shows the points balance for all users, when they got credit or debit of points, and who did it?
Is there any special module that can do that?

Comment: Userpoints does not store *who* assigned them points, it only stores who approved it, in case it had to be approved. You can only find out because of what points were granted.

Comment: I want to show when they got points, like "10/10/2011 - +45 points, 12/10/2011 -20 points"... Is it possible?

Comment: The list at /myuserpoints contains that information. You can also look at the userpoints_txn table to see all information for a transaction (that is how a single point changing "thing" is called in userpoints). Most of that information there should be available to views too.